# Angular Material Sidenav Module is not recognised

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular9, mat-sidenav

I'm using Angular 9.1.11 as well as Angular Material 9.2.4 . I have this problem when I try to import the **MaterialSidenavModule** so i can use components such as *mat-sidenav-container* etc.

Here is my app.module.ts file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import { SidemenuComponent } from './sidemenu/sidemenu.component';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    SidemenuComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSidenavModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The problem is that my IDE (WebStorm) tells me that MatSidenavModule is not an Angular module and won't import it. My sidenav component also has errors that all the material sidenav components i wanted to use are not valid html tags...

Component's HTML template:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidemenu-container">
  <mat-sidenav mode="side" [(opened)]="opened">
    Sidenav content
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content>

    <p>Dummy text</p>

  </mat-sidenav-content>

</mat-sidenav-container>
```

All my other imports work perfectly fine but this one just won't stop ruining my app.
Where did i make a mistake?

Comment: How about to restart your IDE?

Comment: Angular itself also won't compile my code. As i said all the material-sidenav components are not imported for some reason, also as i just noticed, some other material modules experience the same __"not an Angular module"__ problem, but a couple of them work perfectly fine (icon module and button module). So it is not an IDE problem as far as i understand

Answer (score 0):

Soooo, I just solved my problem.

Apparently **Angular Material 9+** won't work if **Ivy**(*Angular's new compilation and rendering pipeline since version **9***) is disabled in your project (*oops* I guess).

I updated the **Material** package once more from version 9 to 10, re-enabled **Ivy** and the app seems to be working perfectly fine after that.